# Restoring Ubuntu 16.04/Windows 7 partitions to new drive with Clonezilla

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, clonezilla

I currently have a 256GB SSD dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 7 which I want to migrate to a new 500GB SSD. I understand I can't restore a complete disk image to a different size drive, but rather do the separate partitions individually.

Questions:

1. Is this easily doable?
2. Do I need to first create equal size partitions on the new disk?
3. Is it possible to increase the size of those respective partitions after restoring from my backup?
4. What is the process for getting the dual boot set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method **is** to restore a complete drive's [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) image to a different size drive (if the target driver is bigger, and it is in your case).

- Please check with

  ```
  sudo parted -ls
  ```

  that the physical sector sizes are the same in the source drive and the target drive. Otherwise there might be problems when you run the computer from the cloned copy.
- If there is a GUID partition table, GPT, you need to fix the backup partition table at the end of the drive, which can be done with `gdisk`, or easier with the shell-script [`gpt-fix`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/UEFI-and-BIOS/stable-alternative#gpt-fix).
- After cloning (or restoring from an image), you can use `gparted` to increase the size of the Ubuntu partitions or create some new partition in order to use the extra space in the target drive.
- If you need to increase the size of the Windows partition, you may need to move the Ubuntu partition(s) in order to get unallocated drive space near the Windows partition, and after that use Windows tools to increase the size with Windows tools (when running Windows). Please notice that moving the the head end of the boot partition (or root partition) of Ubuntu will make it necessary to reinstall the bootloader `grub`.

  So this is somewhat complicated, and it is much easier to create a new partition with the NTFS file system, where you can store data, that can be shared between Ubuntu and Windows.

Edit:

After cloning, please **avoid booting** the computer with both the source drive and the target drive connected. The drive's partition tables are identical and the UUIDs are identical too, so there may be confusion and there might be problems to boot from either of the drives separately afterwards.

(It is OK to boot from an external drive (for example an Ubuntu live drive) and connect the second of the identical drives after booting, if you want to fix something.)

Comment: I gather from the following that sector size is not an issue:                                           Model: ATA LITEONIT LGT-256 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 256GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Model: Seagate FA GoFlex Pro (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Comment: gdisk shows this:                                                                                                     Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Comment: It's actually the Ubuntu partition I would like most to increase the size of, but it is the first partition, then Win7, so I think I'm ok with your suggestion of a new separate partition shared with Ubuntu and Win7.

Comment: @djgap, It looks good :-) I think it will be straightforward to use a Clonezilla image of the whole drive (or clone the whole drive directly). If you are happy with a new separate partition shared with Ubuntu and Win7, I think things will be easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

- Run Clonzilla to make a full device-to-device clone copy onto your larger SSD. (*You just can't go to a smaller destination drive, but bigger is ok*).
- Replace the 250G SSD with the 500G SSD and make sure it boots to both Windows and Ubuntu. Partition sizes will be the same as they were on the 256G SSD.
- Boot a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and use `gparted` to **move/resize** the Ubuntu partition(s) to the rear of the drive (*assuming that Windows was installed first*), enlarging the partition if desired.
- Again, make sure Windows and Ubuntu boot.
- Boot Windows, and use the Windows `Disk Management` app to **resize** the Windows NTFS partition.
- Confirm that both Windows and Ubuntu boot.

**Note**: If you desire to share data/files between Windows and Ubuntu, it's best to create a new clean NTFS partition some time during this process. Both Windows and Ubuntu can use NTFS.

Comment: Ubuntu was installed first, then Win7.

Comment: Regarding your first point, I'm not able to do a direct device-to-device clone copy, I need to back it up to another temporary drive and then restore to the new drive.

Comment: Why can't you clone the disk? Be careful...if you move/resize the Windows partition, it may not boot any more, and you'll need a Windows repair disc to fix it.

Comment: What I mean is that I can't clone the old disk directly to the new disk - I can't connect the 2 drives together, so I have to back up to another drive and then restore from there.

Comment: @djgap you must have a laptop then? How do you plan on imaging it back from another (external) drive? Do you have a Clonezilla CD, or a network-bootable Clonezilla?

Comment: yes it's a laptop, I have a bootable Clonzilla USB..  I looked for a m.2 - USB enclosure but they all seem to need USB 3.0 and my laptop only has 2.0

Comment: Does your laptop have a CD/DVD drive? It's typically a SATA drive. Drives in external enclosures may not make working clone drives because of some of the USB->SATA converter boards... and must be reformatted before/after being used in such.

Comment: no CD/DVD drive :(

Comment: Do you have access to a desktop machine with two extra SATA ports? Otherwise, as you say, you'll somehow need to image it off/back.

Comment: No I don't..  I'll get the new drive tomorrow and try the backup/restore.. if I have any further issues I'll post a new thread, thanks for the help.